# Close JIternalFrame if it is open

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have a `JInternalFrame FRMCadUsuarios` that calls another `JInternalFrame  FRMCadNiveisAcesso` when I click a _ from my `JInternalFrame  FRMCadUsuarios`. But I want to check if the `FRMCadNiveisAcesso` is already open in `JDesktopPanel` and if it is, I want to close it and open a new one when click on the `JInternalFrame FRMCadUsuarios button`.

I need to close if it is already open and open a new one when click on the `FRMCadUsuarios` `JInternalFrame` because they open differently.

When I open the `JInternalFrame FRMCadNiveisAcesso` by the main `JFrame` it opens a way and when I open by clicking the `JInternalFrame FRMCadUsuarios` it opens another way because it catches a variable of `JInternalFrame FRMCadUsuarios`.

```
FRMPrincipalModulosAdmFinOper frmPrincipalModulosAdmFinOper = new FRMPrincipalModulosAdmFinOper();   
if(frmPrincipalModulosAdmFinOper.getFrmCadNiveisAcesso() != null){
    frmPrincipalModulosAdmFinOper.getFrmCadNiveisAcesso().dispose();
}
FRMCadNiveisAcesso frmCadNiveisAcesso = new FRMCadNiveisAcesso(painelx);
painelx.add(frmCadNiveisAcesso);  
frmCadNiveisAcesso.setPosicao();
frmCadNiveisAcesso.setVisible(true);  
frmCadNiveisAcesso.getTxtUsuario().setText(this.txtUsuario.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Static variable of FRMCadNiveisAcesso .
When ever you initialize a object for FRMCadNiveisAcesso  (either through Main frame or JInternalFrame  _ FRMCadUsuarios) store that object in static variable.

and before creating new object for FRMCadNiveisAcessoe (on button click in FRMCadUsuarios ) check if static object is null or not , if not null then dispose that frame and create new one

sudo code
write inside button action listner

```
if (staicObjectOfFrame != null)
{
staicObjectOfFrame.dispose();
}
staicObjectOfFrame=new FRMCadNiveisAcesso();
staicObjectOfFrame.setvisble(true);
```